# Limit of $\sqrt{x^2+3x}+x$ when $x\to-\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

Limit of $ \lim_{x\to -\infty}(\sqrt{x^2+3x}+x)$, I know that the final answer is $-3/2$, my question is about Wolfram Alpha step by step solution:

$$x+\sqrt{x^2+3x}=\frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2+3x})(x-\sqrt{x^2+3x})}{x-\sqrt{x^2+3x}}$$

$$=-\frac{3x}{x-\sqrt{x^2+3x}}$$

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}-\frac{3x}{x-\sqrt{x^2+3x}}$$

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}-\frac{3x}{x-\sqrt{x^2+3x}}=-3$$

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x}{x-\sqrt{x^2+3x}}=-3\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x}{x-\sqrt{x^2+3x}}$$

$$\frac{x}{x-\sqrt{x^2+3x}}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3x}}{x}}$$

$$-3\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x}{x\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3x}}{x}\right)}$$

To prepare the product $\frac{1}{1-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3x}}{x}}$ for solution by l'Hopital's rule, write it as $\frac{x}{x\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3x}}{x}\right)}$

$$-3\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x}{x\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3x}}{x}\right)}$$

> Is it correct to use L'Hopital here like Wolfram did?

Comment: This might be made correct but, first and foremost, this is just **absurd**, the limit $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac1{1-\frac1x\sqrt{x^2+3x}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac1{1+\sqrt{1+\frac3x}}$$ being elementary..

Comment: In addition, note that the phrase $$\text{Limit of $ \lim_{x\to -\infty}(\sqrt{x^2+3x}+x)$}$$ is also absurd and see your revised title for a correct formulation.

Comment: Wolfram does tend to overcomplicate things a bit; of course, to an AI, this doesn't look like an over-complication. It reminds me of the old joke about "how to put out a fire if you have a water tap and an empty bucket?" followed by "how to put out a fire if you have a water tap and a bucket full of water?"

Comment: I've written up your question with MathJax, though there were a lot of redundant formulae. Please let me know if I've changed the meaning of anything. Next time, if you use MathJax, it would make it easier for everyone to search and read :) thanks https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Wolfram is free to do that because for all finite $x$,

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{xf(x)}{xg(x)}$$ by "unsimplification", so that the limits are the same.

You can even write a "modified L'Hospital rule" theorem saying

$$\lim\frac fg=\lim\frac{f'}{g'}=\lim\frac{f+xf'}{g+xg'},$$ if that has any use.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to render

$\sqrt{x^2+3x}+x=\frac{3x}{\sqrt{x^2+3x}-x}$

The next step is to complete the square on $x^2+3x$ getting

$x^2+3x=(x+(3/2))^2-(9/4)$

Use this to show that for negative $x$ with $x<-3$ (why?):

$-x-(3/2)<\sqrt{x^2+3x}<-x$

and then

$-\frac{3x}{2x+(3/2)}<\frac{3x}{\sqrt{x^2+3x}-x}<-(3/2)$

Now get the limit from the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

$$
x+\sqrt{x^2+3x}=\frac{x^2-({x^2+3x})}{x-\sqrt{x^2+3x}}=\frac{-3x}{x-\sqrt{x^2+3x}}=\frac{-3}{1+\sqrt{1+\frac3x}}\stackrel{\tiny x\to-\infty}{\longrightarrow} -\frac 32
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+3x}+x\right)$$
Multiply by the conjugate

\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{x^2+3x}+x &= \left(\sqrt{x^2+3x}+x\right) \cdot \left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3x}-x}{\sqrt{x^2+3x}-x}\right)\\
&= \frac{\left(\sqrt{x^2+3x}\right)^2-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+3x}-x}\\
&= \frac{x^2+3x-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+3x}-x}\\
&=\frac{3x}{\sqrt{x^2+3x}-x}
\end{aligned}
Also 
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\left(\frac{3x}{\sqrt{x^2+3x}-x}\right)&= 3\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+3x}-x}\right)\\
&=3\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2\left(1+\frac{3}{x}\right)}-x}\right)\\
&=3\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{x}}-x}\right)
\end{aligned}
Let $x \to -\infty \implies \sqrt{x^2} = -x$
\begin{aligned}
3\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\left(\frac{x}{-x\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{x}}-x}\right)
\end{aligned}
Divide by $x$
\begin{aligned}
3\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\left(\frac{\frac{x}{x}}{-\frac{x\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{x}}}{x}-\frac{x}{x}}\right) = 3\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\left( \frac{1}{-\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{x}}-1}\right)
\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}
3\cdot \frac{\lim _{x\to -\infty }\left(1\right)}{\lim _{x\to -\infty }\left(-\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{x}}-1\right)} =3\cdot \frac{1}{-2} = -\frac{3}{2}
\end{aligned}
So

> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+3x}+x\right) = -\frac{3}{2}$$

---

**Note:**
\begin{aligned}
\lim _{x\to -\infty }\left(-\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{x}}-1\right) = \lim _{x\to -\infty }\left(-\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{x}}\right)-\lim _{x\to -\infty }\left(1\right)
= 1 - (-1) =2
\end{aligned}